# Ember Handlebars not automatically putting model in scope

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Typically, Ember automatically puts the route's model in scope when rendering a handlebars template:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

Renders:

```
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

For some reason, it's not doing that for me with a particular route. I'm just getting an empty `<h1></h1>`. However, if I manually put it into scope:

```
<h1>{{ model.title }}</h1>
```

Then it works as expected. What might be causing this behavior? My route is basic:

```
MeetingsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find('meeting', params.id)

`export default MeetingsShowRoute`
```

And both the relevant view and controller is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is probably extending the controller class, when it should be extending object controller.

```
MeetingsShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend ...
```

Rule of thumb:

#### No Model backed controller

```
FooControler = Ember.Controller.extend
```

#### Single Model backed controller

```
FooControler = Ember.ObjectController.extend
```

#### Collection Model backed controller

```
FooControler = Ember.ArrayController.extend
```